# wpf c# Is there anyway to force a list box to take a new line

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Program reads an input file and displays its contents to a list box.

However with longer strings the list box will just use one line to display all the text which is annoying.
Is there anyway to force the list box to create a new line after x amount of characters. This is a wpf app

[image: Image for reference]

Comment: You can add a new line character to your string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an ItemTemplate with a wrapping TextBlock and disable horizontal scrolling:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ...>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```